# Can you specify axis ranges on proc kde plots?

Tags: sas

Is it possible to specify axis ranges in the kde procedure? Not in a secondary sgplot. As in the following code:

> proc kde data=have; bivar y / plots=contour; by z; run;

The plots I get from proc kde are gorgeous but the axes aren't the scale I need. I can fix the axes easily in a scatter plot using the data output by proc kde but the plot is hideous. So I guess secondary question is how do I make the sgplot look like the proc kde plot.

From proc kde:

[image: From proc kde]

From sgplot:

[image: From sgplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `gridl` option to set the lower grid limit and `gridu` option to set the upper limit.
You may use them like the following:

```
data bivnormal;
  seed = 1283470;
  do i = 1 to 1000;
     z1 = rannor(seed);
     z2 = rannor(seed);
     x = 3*z1+z2;
     output;
  end;
  drop seed;
run;

ods graphics on;
proc kde data=bivnormal;
  univar x /gridl=-14 gridu=14 plots=(histdensity);
run;
ods graphics off;
```

If you want to do more with this graph, try output the data of graph. So you can use `proc sgplot` later.

```
ods output HistogramDensity=HistogramDensity;
ods graphics on;
proc kde data=bivnormal;
  univar x /gridl=-14 gridu=14 plots=(histdensity);
run;
ods graphics off;
ods output close;
```